# AngularJS conditional to display value inside ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS express to display either a date or "NO" based on another property within the ng-repeat loop.

If requirement.MyStatus == "Y" then I want to display requirement.MyDate else if requirement.MyStatus == "N", display "NO"

```
<tr ng-repeat="requirement in listItems" ng-class="requirement | rowFilter">
                                <td ng-bind="requirement.MyStatus"></td>

                                <td ng-bind="requirement.MyDate | date:'shortDate'"></td> 

                            </tr>
```

I tried the following expression but it did not work

{{requirement.metStatus == "N" | iif : "requirement.MyDate | date:'shortDate'" : "NO" }}

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
{{requirement.metStatus == "N" ? (requirement.MyDate | date:'shortDate') : "NO" }}
```

Comment: Role is reversed i think `==` should equate with 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<td ng-bind="requirement.MyDate | date:'shortDate'"></td>
```

to

```
<td ng-bind="requirement.MyDate | date:'shortDate'" ng-if="requirement.MyStatus == 'Y'"></td>
```